# How to describe lists with different ordering schemes?

Tags: expressions, terminology, programming

I'm [helping someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31684567/5103770) copy a list of lines a certain number of times into a new list, and I don't know how to describe the list that we're creating.  For example, let's copy a list composed of 1, 2, and 3. Copy it three times. The results can be ordered in two ways.

Method 1: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3

Method 2: 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3

**How can I describe the different orderings?** Can I say "Method 1 is ordered by _____, while Method 2 is ordered _____ly?

The closest answer I can come up with is to say "Method 1 is **sorted by number**." It doesn't make sense to say "Method 2 is **unsorted**," however, as it implies a lack of order.

Comment: Do you mean *collated* or are you after something more specific?

Comment: You can say that method 1 results in a *sorted list* and Method 2 just *concatenates* the lists.

Comment: _Collated_ is what I was looking for. _Concatenated_ is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest term I can think of to describe Method 2 would be "collated." It's a printing-related term, where if you have, say, a 3 page print job with 4 copies, the pages come out as follows:

Collated: 1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3; 1, 2, 3
Uncollated: 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4

I've never really heard the term "collate" used outside of printing, but the dictionary tells me it's a general term for collecting in proper order. So while this may not be idiomatically common for your particular situation, it could be a good way to explain it by analogy.

I might also say Method 1 is "grouped by number" as opposed to sorted. While it's obviously sorted in numerical order, in a context like this, sorted is clearly a bit ambivalent.